# JQuery Chosen Selectbox in Container with overflow: hidden

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to use chosen to style Selectboxes in my application. Unfortunately it acts different then the native select boxes when it comes to containers with overflow: hidden.

When i open up the popup it will not be (or pertially be) visible.

**Html**:

```
<div class="layoutContainer">
    <select class="select-chosen">
        <option>Option A</option>
        <option>Option B</option>
        <option>Option C</option>
    </select>
    <select>
        <option>Option A</option>
        <option>Option B</option>
        <option>Option C</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
.layoutContainer{
    background: #660066;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 40px;
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".select-chosen").chosen({
        disable_search : true,
        width: "150px"
    });
});
```

And here's the corresponding [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZJ73j/1/)

Is there a solution for this problem?

Comment: I doubt you can fix it without removing the `overflow: hidden;` - why is it there in the first place, maybe we can find a workaround?

Comment: It's there because the environment i'm using (A JavaScript layout engine) prevents its containers from scrolling that way.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue today, did some basic research and came up with a quick solution.

In the function `results_show()`, find the following lines:

```
this.search_field.focus();
this.search_field.val(this.search_field.val());
this.winnow_results();
```

Below that, add the code that follows.

**Case #A**

Your container is the window.

Code:

```
var _cont=$(window);
```

**Case #B**

You use some other container that is set to overflow hidden. In this example this will be an element given the class name `.layoutContainer`.

Code:

```
var _cont=$(this.container).parentsUntil('.layoutContainer').parent();
```

---

Then, below either of the lines above, add the following code:

```
var _containerHeight = _cont.height();
var _elementHeight = $(this.container).find('ul').height();
var _elementTop = $(this.container).offset().top;
var _xh=$(this.container).outerHeight();

if (_containerHeight - (_elementHeight + _elementTop) + _xh < 0) {
  this.dropdown.css({
      bottom: _xh,
      top: 'auto'
  });
} else {
  this.dropdown.css({
      top: _xh,
      bottom: 'auto'
  });
}
```

And that's it.

**Explanation**

We simply gather all required information to compute whether the droplist overflows the wrapping container (that is set to overscroll hidden). Once we have that, we check if it is overflowing and if yes, we set it to use bottom-based positioning instead of top-based. Otherwise we revert to top-based.

This works because the droplist is positioned relative to the *Chosen* container, thus the usage of `bottom` results in the list being aligned topwards.

**Considerations**

The `.chosen-drop` box-shadow is kind of annoying once the droplist gets positioned above the element (instead of below). To counteract this, i dynamically added a class if the element is overflowing, and remove it if the element is not.

**Disclaimer**

This code is **far** from perfect! I didn't do any optimization. I supplied it to myself as a quick fix and wanted to share it with other seekers who run into the same problem.

Please feel free to post any improvements to this.

This code assumes the classic, basic version of *Chosen* at the current version (1.1.0).

Answer (score 0):

unavoidable since the container element, is well, `overflow :hidden` that's just how CSS works. The only way around this is to render the drop down outside of the container and then use absolute positioning.

Comment: The `selectmenu` feature of the new jquery-ui selectmenu branch handles it the way i would expect it (absolute positioning of the dropwown) but unfortunately it screws up many other important things up to now.

Comment: It is not unavoidable per se. It is a default by design and it's correct that way. But it can be worked around easily.

Answer (score 0):

see this if its [link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/richapandey/ZJ73j/2/)

```
.layoutContainer{
    background: #660066;
    height: 40px;
}
.overflowHidden{
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem since the container must stay overflow:hidden all the time or some things may be visible that shouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem - needed overflow: hidden, but the height was changing (fading in and out new elements) so i solved it with empty div with clear: both at the end of container.

Comment: I don't think this is related to the question author's problem.